# How can we split one huge org.w3c.dom.NodeList into List of NodeLists in Java?

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I am having a NodeList with size over 1500, so I want a List of NodeLists with each length of 300.
Is there any easy method to get it done? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you talking about a 2d List? Edit: Why would you want to break it up?

Comment: Actually I have to process that NodeList, but due to its size processing time is getting delayed, so want to divide into multiple smaller lists and process each list

Comment: 1500 objects shouldn't take that long. And if if it's faster to process 5 NodeLists than 1 NodeList of equal objects. This tells you there is something wrong with your recursion/logic. Honestly, I would focus on finding out why your code is running slow rather than finding a work around.